# Delete all n-lavels of categories in select using PHP

Tags: php

```
function delete_subcats($id) {
    global $con;
    $sql = "select * from `add_category` where `id` = ".$id;
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_row($res)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            delete_subcats($row['id']);
        }
    }

    mysqli_query($con,"delete from `add_category` where `id` = ".$id);
}
```

Comment: So, what's your issue/question? Please edit your question to include a proper explanation.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Btw, if the id exists, it looks like your code will create an infinite loop since the function then will call itself with the same argument...

Answer (score 0):

you can give foreign key of parent id than after fire simple delete query.

**OR**

you can use recursive function.

```
function delete_category($cat_id, $table = "nested_category") {
        $query = $this->db->select('id,pid')
                        ->from($table)
                        ->where('pid', $cat_id)
                        ->get()->result();
        foreach ($query as $row)
            $this->delete_category($row->id);
        $this->db->delete($table, array("id" => $cat_id));
    }
```

**OR**

```
function delete_subcats($id) {
    global $con;
    $sql = "select * from `add_category` where `pid` = ".$id;
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(!empty($res)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            delete_subcats($row['id']);
        }
    }

    mysqli_query($con,"delete from `add_category` where `id` = ".$id);
}
```

Comment: Have I missed something in the question? How do you know OP uses query builder?